# How precise the value of Java's Math.PI is?

Tags: java, math

What is the largest N that I can get PI's Nth digit?

Comment: Are you asking about floating point representation?  If so, what was wrong with the definition of floating point in the Java reference manual or on Wikipedia?

Comment: Are you asking how far PI is defined? From the source: public static final double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;

Comment: Its as precise as any double.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`public static final double     PI =    3.141592653589793d`

so `N = 16`

that's what **API says** here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Math.PI

---

**but** indeed **source code of Math.class says**:

`public static final double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;`

and here `N = 21`

anyway - that's a bit wierd ;)

Comment: The precision of an IEEE 754 64 bit double is about 16 digits, which is exactly the number of digits in `3.141592653589793d`

Comment: Nothing weird about it. This simply means that 21 digits were entered. It does NOT mean that 21 digits are stored accurately in the number, were you to write that value back out.

Comment: 16 digits it is - here's how: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 5):

This is what is written in the source code:

```
/**
 * The {@code double} value that is closer than any other to
 * <i>pi</i>, the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its
 * diameter.
 */
public static final double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
```

Answer (score 2):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Math.PI

Answer (score 2):

From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Math.PI)

```
public static final double  PI  3.141592653589793d
```

it appears as if it's defined out to 15 decimal places. There's a little bit more discussion on the subject in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825559/is-java-lang-math-pi-equal-to-gccs-m-pi).

Answer (score 1):

In the source code:

```
/**
 * The {@code double} value that is closer than any other to
 * <i>pi</i>, the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its
 * diameter.
 */
public static final double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
```

Answer (score -2):

The Java constant of Pi is an approximation. The precise value of Pi is irrelevant in most of the computing.